# "Lock wait timeout exceeded" without no process in processlist

Tags: mysql, locking

I've gotten the next error while trying to perform some bunch deletion with reasonable limit:

```
query=(DELETE FROM `A` WHERE `id` < 123456 LIMIT 1000)

exception=(1205, 'Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction')
```

And

```
mysql> SHOW OPEN TABLES like 'A';
+----------+----------------------+--------+-------------+
| Database | Table                | In_use | Name_locked |
+----------+----------------------+--------+-------------+
| D        | A                    |      3 |           0 |
+----------+----------------------+--------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.22 sec)
```

I see that where is might be a deadlock, but `show full processlist` outputs only itself. Where to dig into?

*InnoDB, MySQL 5.5*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means there is a transaction that should be committed. Check other sessions or other applications which may operate with this table.

Comment: I assume that any other active sessions should be in `show full processlist` output.  Am I right?

Comment: SHOW PROCESSLIST shows open sessions, and there should be the session that has transaction, but Info field (query) can be empty. Check locked tables with SHOW OPEN TABLES command.

Comment: but there is no session shown in `SHOW PROCESSLIST`, and `SHOW OPEN TABLES` shows non-zero number of locks on my table.

Comment: To force SHOW PROCESSLIST view all sessions grant PROCESS privilege. SHOW OPEN TABLES returned In_use = 3, it means that table is used.

Answer (score 0):

Also there could be unclosed transacions after SELECTs. I've solved (I hope) such case adding commit/rollback after separate (not some transaciotn parts) SELECTs.

This idea has looked strange for me, so I'd spent some time for other atempts before I've tried it. And it has helped.